# get a substring with regex

Tags: java, regex, string

how can I get the string form `<a` to the first `>` or instead of it, how can I get value of href?

I tried it but it's get from open `a` to close `span`

```
String str = "<span class=\"foo\"><a href=\"http://www.foo.com/bla\" boo=\"blabla\">click here</a></span>";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("<a href.*>");
Matcher matcher2 = pattern2.matcher(str);
matcher.find();
matcher.group();
```

Comment: Use a parser instead.

Comment: If you *must* use RegEx for whatever reason you could try: `(?<=a href=")([^">]+)(?=")` if your string is unescaped.